# Create and populate a dataframe using the unique values of another dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
  X1   X2   X3
0  a    c    a
1  b    e    c
2  c  nan    e
3  d  nan  nan
```

I would like to create a new dataframe `newdf` which has one column (`uentries`) that contains the unique entries of `df` and the three columns of `df` which are filled with `0` and `1` depending on whether the the entry of `uentries` exists in the respective column in `df`.

My **desired output** would therefore look as follows (`uentries` does not need to be ordered):

```
  uentries  X1  X2  X3
0        a   1   0   1
1        b   1   0   0
2        c   1   1   1
3        d   1   0   0
4        e   0   1   1
```

Currently, I do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'X2': ['c', 'e', 'nan', 'nan'],
                   'X3': ['a', 'c', 'e', 'nan']})

uniqueEntries = set([x for x in np.ravel(df.values) if str(x) != 'nan'])

newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf['uentries'] = list(uniqueEntries)

for coli in df.columns:
    newdf[coli] = newdf['uentries'].isin(df[coli])

newdf.ix[:, 'X1':'X3'] = newdf.ix[:, 'X1':'X3'].astype(int)
```

which gives me the desired output.

Is it possible to fill `newdf` in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way to approach this problem using `pd.value_counts`.

```
newdf = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
newdf['uentries'] = newdf.index
newdf = newdf[['uentries', 'X1','X2','X3']]
newdf

uentries X1 X2 X3
a   a   1   0   1
b   b   1   0   0
c   c   1   1   1
d   d   1   0   0
e   e   0   1   1
nan nan 0   2   1
```

Then you can just drop the row with the `nan` values:

```
newdf.drop(['nan'])

uentries X1 X2 X3
a   a   1   0   1
b   b   1   0   0
c   c   1   1   1
d   d   1   0   0
e   e   0   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would be the easiest way to get rid of the `nan` row and to use `a:e` as a column rather than as index?

Comment: @Cleb I edited my answer. I got rid of the row with the `nan` values and created a `uentries` column. The index remained a:e.

Comment: Thanks, works fine and seems more efficient than the solution I have. I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on the other answers' quality.

Comment: Great. I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'X2': ['c', 'e', 'nan', 'nan'],
                   'X3': ['a', 'c', 'e', 'nan']})
print df
  X1   X2   X3
0  a    c    a
1  b    e    c
2  c  nan    e
3  d  nan  nan

a = pd.get_dummies(df['X1']).sum()
b = pd.get_dummies(df['X2']).sum()
c = pd.get_dummies(df['X3']).sum()

print pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1, keys=['X1','X2','X3']).fillna(0)
     X1  X2  X3
a     1   0   1
b     1   0   0
c     1   1   1
d     1   0   0
e     0   1   1
nan   0   2   1
```

If you use `np.nan` in test data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'X2': ['c', 'e', np.nan, np.nan],
                   'X3': ['a', 'c', 'e', np.nan]})
print df

a = pd.get_dummies(df['X1']).sum()
b = pd.get_dummies(df['X2']).sum()
c = pd.get_dummies(df['X3']).sum()

print pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1, keys=['X1','X2','X3']).fillna(0)
   X1  X2  X3
a   1   0   1
b   1   0   0
c   1   1   1
d   1   0   0
e   0   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you then avoid the single calls of `get_dummies` when you have a large number of columns?

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df[c]).any().astype(int) for c in df.columns], axis=1, keys=df.columns).fillna(0)`